# How can I get rid of the Start tab in Foxit Reader?

Tags: foxit-reader

Whenever I open a PDF document, Foxit Reader will also have a **Start** tab open.

[image]

Can this tab be disabled somewhow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tab can be disabled in the preferences.

1. Go to **File** → **Preferences**.

   [image: File menu]
2. In the **General** section, uncheck the option **Show Start page**.

   [image: Preferences dialog]

Comment: There is no such preference in OSX. Is there a means to do so on this platform? In fact, there are hardly *any* settings on this platform.

Comment: No such option on the Ubuntu as well.